# 'int' object is not subscriptable error - trying to search through 2d array to find specific index

Tags: python, iteration, finance

I am using a 2d array and am trying to search through it and update it like a database, I am going to try to put this on a website so I'm just using a 2d array for now. However when I try using a for loop to search through the index of the 2d array it comes up with the error.

This is the whole code. I am talking about specifically the sell function, I want it to go through the values in the 2d array to look at the 0th index where the ticker will be if it matches then I want the 1st index (quantity) of that iteration to be minused by the quantity input by user. How do I get this to work?

`import requests

```
ticker = input("ticker?")
quantity = int(input("quantity?"))

portfolio = [1000,[ticker,"quatity","datebought"]]

def getshareprice (ticker):
    url = f"https://api.twelvedata.com/price?symbol={ticker}&apikey={TDKEY}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    price = data.get('price')

    return float(price)

def buy(ticker,quantity):
    allocated_funds = float(getshareprice(ticker)*quantity)
    if allocated_funds<int(portfolio[0]):
        portfolio[0] -= allocated_funds
        portfolio.append([ticker,quantity,"datebought"])
        print ("you have bought",quantity,"shares of:",ticker,"for",allocated_funds,",in cash you have",portfolio[0])
    else:
        purchasable = int(portfolio[0])/getshareprice(ticker) 
        print("not enough funds to allocate transaction")

def sell(ticker,quantity):
    for i in portfolio:
        if i[0] == ticker:
            i[1] -= quantity
        else:
            print("not enough shares to allocate transaction")`
```

Another way I was thinking of doing this was to just add another array into the 2d array saying how many shares the user wanted to sell, however this comes with the same problem of searching through the 2d array trying to find the correct ticker.
It needs to search through to see how many shares they have as the user should not be able to sell more shares than they own.
This way I could try to implement a portfolio history as well.

Comment: `portofolio[0] = 1000`, so `for i in portofolio` gets `1000` in the first iteration and you can't subscribe that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The first value of `i` in `for i in portfolio` will be `1000`. You then do `if i[0] == ticker:`... this translated to `if 1000[0] == ticker`. `1000[0]` is nonsense, and you get this error.

Comment: Your `portfolio` variable is not a list of entries.  It is one entry.  You should actually use a dictionary instead, where the key is the ticker symbol.  That way, you don't have to search at all -- Python will do it for you.

Comment: ok thank you for helping for helping me realise why. also, the dictionary seems much better thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a design like this.  "portfolio" becomes the database of your holdings, with a special ticker called "cash" that has your cash.

```
import requests

ticker = input("ticker?")
quantity = int(input("quantity?"))

portfolio = {
    'cash': [1000, None]
}

def getshareprice (ticker):
    url = f"https://api.twelvedata.com/price?symbol={ticker}&apikey={TDKEY}"

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    price = data.get('price')

    return float(price)

def buy(ticker,quantity):
    allocated_funds = float(getshareprice(ticker)*quantity)
    if allocated_funds < portfolio['cash'][0]:
        portfolio['cash'][0] -= allocated_funds
        if ticker not in portfolio:
            portfolio[ticker] = [0, None]
        portfolio[ticker][0] += quantity
        print ("you have bought",quantity,"shares of:",ticker,"for",allocated_funds,",in cash you have",portfolio['cash'][0])
    else:
        purchasable = int(portfolio['cash'][0])/getshareprice(ticker) 
        print("not enough funds to allocate transaction")

def sell(ticker,quantity):
    if ticker not in portfolio:
        print("You don't own that ticker")
    elif portfolio[ticker][0] > quantity:
        print("not enough shares to allocate transaction")
    else:
        portfolio[ticker][0] -= quantity

buy('MSFT',10)
sell('INTL',9)
sell('MSFT',5)
buy(ticker,quantity)
```

Comment: thank you for this it's so much better than having to search through it, can i ask what the none is for index 1 in portfolio?

Comment: That's where you would store the "date bought", if you need it.  I didn't include that code.